# Query is performing full scan after creating the index also

Tags: mysql, sql

my query is performing full table scan.

```
mysql> explain select dr.* from iflora_delivery_rules dr where dr.order_end_date >= "2013-05-01 09:28:05" and dr.deactive_date is null and ( (brand_id = 1 and dr.source_code in ( '1.1.1.1' , '1.1.1' , '1.1' , '1' )) or (brand_id = 0 and dr.source_code in ( '1.1.1.1' , '1.1.1' , '1.1' , '1' ))) order by precedence desc,brand_id desc,source_code desc;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dr    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  867 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I was created indexes on   columns  brand_id,source_code

```
mysql> create index idx_brand_n1 on iflora_delivery_rules(brand_id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>  create index idx_source_code_n1 on iflora_delivery_rules(source_code);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> explain select dr.* from iflora_delivery_rules dr where dr.order_end_date >= "2013-05-01 09:28:05" and dr.deactive_date is null and ( (brand_id = 1 and dr.source_code in ( '1.1.1.1' , '1.1.1' , '1.1' , '1' )) or (brand_id = 0 and dr.source_code in ( '1.1.1.1' , '1.1.1' , '1.1' , '1' ))) order by precedence desc,brand_id desc,source_code desc;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                   | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dr    | ALL  | idx_brand_n1,idx_source_code_n1 | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  867 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table

```
mysql> show create table iflora_delivery_rules\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: iflora_delivery_rules
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `iflora_delivery_rules` (
  `row_mod` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_create` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_rule_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `source_code` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `rotation_weight` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_day_of_week` varchar(7) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_day_of_week` varchar(7) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `charge_type` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `lead_min_days` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lead_max_days` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precedence` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `charge_name` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `display_colour` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_long_desc` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_short_desc` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `exec_country_type` varchar(5) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `shipping_method_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rule_line_id` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `deactive_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `version_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_rule_type` varchar(5) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `iflora_delivery_rules_n1` (`shipping_method_id`),
  KEY `idx_exec_country_type_n1` (`exec_country_type`),
  KEY `idx_rotation_weight_n1` (`rotation_weight`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: pls reformat: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: `source_code` is the same in both parts of the `OR`, do you need to repeat it? I think pulling it out of the `OR` will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `OR` in the WHERE clause prevents it from using the indexes. Since `dr.source_code` is the same in both cases, it doesn't need to be in there. This query is equivalent and should use one of the indexes.

```
select dr.* from iflora_delivery_rules dr
where dr.order_end_date >= "2013-05-01 09:28:05"
and dr.deactive_date is null
and brand_id in (0, 1)
and dr.source_code in ( '1.1.1.1' , '1.1.1' , '1.1' , '1' )
order by precedence desc,brand_id desc,source_code desc;
```

It might be even better to create a composite index:

```
create index idx_brand_id_source_code_n1 on iflora_delivery_rules(brand_id, source_code);
```

But since you're using `IN` conditions on both fields, I'm not sure if it would be able to use this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this

```
explain 
SELECT dr.* 
FROM iflora_delivery_rules dr 
WHERE
    dr.brand_id IN(1,0) 
    AND dr.source_code in ( '1.1.1.1' , '1.1.1' , '1.1' , '1' )
    AND dr.order_end_date >= "2013-05-01 09:28:05" 
    AND dr.deactive_date is null 
ORDER BY precedence desc, brand_id desc, source_code desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think the OR should cause issues it is easy to remove this to confirm by using an UNION

```
SELECT dr.* 
FROM iflora_delivery_rules dr 
WHERE dr.order_end_date >= "2013-05-01 09:28:05" 
AND dr.deactive_date IS NULL 
AND brand_id = 1 
AND dr.source_code IN ( '1.1.1.1' , '1.1.1' , '1.1' , '1' )
UNION
SELECT dr.* 
FROM iflora_delivery_rules dr 
WHERE dr.order_end_date >= "2013-05-01 09:28:05" 
AND dr.deactive_date IS NULL 
AND brand_id = 0 
AND dr.source_code IN ( '1.1.1.1' , '1.1.1' , '1.1' , '1' )
ORDER BY precedence DESC,brand_id DESC,source_code DESC
```

However I suspect that the issue might be your choice of indexes. MySQL will only use one index on a table within a query, hence it would either choose the index on brand_id or source_code. However at a guess looking at your example select neither of these narrow down the number of records that much hence quite possibly ignored (it is only worth MySQL to use the index if the index narrows down the results substantially, if it doesn't then it ignores the index).

I would be tempted to use a key covering multiple columns. At least brand_id and source_code, and quite probably order_end_date as well.